# dynamic WTForms SelectField shows the column-title of table in the db

Tags: flask, dynamic, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to pull data from an SQL-Table 'School' via flask sql-alchemy into a SelectField:

form:

```
school_choices = [(School.id, School.name) for school in School.query.all()]
school = SelectField('Your school', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=school_choices)
```

routes:

```
def register():
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
form = RegistrationForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
    user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password, school=form.school.data)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Your account has been created! You are now able to log in', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

model:

```
class School(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
```

However, it somehow only displays "School.name", just how it is written in the form.
Also, the number of entries it should display is correct (3, since 3 entries of schools are in the database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your list comprehension that builds the values for the select field and the difference between the rendering of column attributes on the class vs the class instance:

```py
school_choices = [(School.id, School.name) for school in School.query.all()]
```

In the above comprehension, in each loop `school` (lowercase 's') is an instance of the class `School` (uppercase 'S').

In sqlalchemy, the string representation of a column attribute on a Class (not instance of a class) returns the database identity of the column, e.g.: `"<tablename>.<columnname>"`, or in this case `"school.name"`. This is how queries are built, e.g. try running `print(School.__table__.select())`, it will print `SELECT school.id, school.name FROM School`. The column identities in that query come from "stringifying" the Column instance.

However, when we access a column attribute on an instance of a class, e.g. `school = School(name="myschool")`, we get the value of the column that is stored in the database. E.g. `print(school.school)  # myschool`.

Looking at your list comprehension above, you create a tuple of `(School.id, School.name)` for each `school` instance in the database. Notice the uppercase 'S' for 'School', which means that you end up rendering the string representation of your column's database identity for each school in the database when your template renders. The answer is as simple as changing your comprehension to:

```py
school_choices = [(school.id, school.name) for school in School.query.all()]
```

...but understanding the difference is fairly important when using sqlalchemy and python in general.